# Does parameter files get exported along with workflow?

Tags: informatica

I exported the workflow from dev and imported into test. But the parameter file hasn't been copied to test along with wf. DO i have to manually copy the parameter files into test or is any procedure for that to do so.

Informatica powercenter

Thanks,
Teja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two ways to do this,
1) **shared directory**, in this you have to only give the path to the directory in which your parameter file is existing.
2) you have do the manually copy the parameter file into the test.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to copy the parameter files manually.

Answer (score 0):

It would be manually copied.
Note that the parameter might need modification as to the folder name if the target repository is different from test.